# Obj-C: Issue with Unicode character composition involving UTF-8 literals

Tags: objective-c, unicode, utf-8, normalization, unicode-normalization

I'm facing a problem with composing Unicode characters in Obj-C, described by the next example code, that tries to combine 'e' with acute accent:

```
NSLog(@"Composing with Unicode literal: '%@'\nComposing with UTF-8 literal: '%@'",
      [[NSString stringWithUTF8String:"e\u0301"]
       precomposedStringWithCanonicalMapping],
      [[NSString stringWithUTF8String:"e\xc2\xb4"] // "\xc\xb4" is UTF-8 rep of "\u0301"
       precomposedStringWithCanonicalMapping]);
```

The output is:

```
Composing with Unicode literal: 'é'
Composing with UTF-8 literal: 'e´'
```

So the code yields the correct result only when the acute is specified as \u literal, while using UTF-8 representation appears to produce wrong result. My question: Is there a way to use UTF-8 nevertheless?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the wrong UTF-8 encoding for the combining accent.

Change `\xc2\xb4` to `\xcc\x81`. This change will give you the expected result.

The accent you were using in the non-combining accent.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong acute accent for combining:

```
NSString *utf = [[NSString stringWithUTF8String:"e\xcc\x81"] precomposedStringWithCanonicalMapping];  // "\xc\xb4" is UTF-8 rep of "\u0301"
NSLog(@"utf: %@",utf);
```

Output:

> utf: é

See [COMBINING ACUTE ACCENT](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0301/index.htm)